# When `stty tostop` is set, how come processes not in the same session can still write to the tty?

Tags: tty

I have the following shell interaction:

```
[OP@localhost linux]$ tty
/dev/pts/7
[OP@localhost linux]$ stty tostop
[OP@localhost linux]$
```

In another terminal, I type:

```
[OP@localhost linux]$ echo hello > /dev/pts/7
```

Back in the original, I see:

```
[OP@localhost linux]$ tty
/dev/pts/7
[OP@localhost linux]$ stty tostop
[OP@localhost linux]$ hello
```

Why is this? Shouldn't the echo process be stopped?

Comment: Yes, but the question is asking why processes in another session don't experience this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `termios(3)` manpage say:

> `TOSTOP`
>
> Send the `SIGTTOU` signal to the *process group* of a **background process** which tries to write to **its controlling terminal**.

Your `echo` process[1] is not a background process, and does not try to write to **its** controlling tty.

Also notice the "process group" bit; a job control signal like `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`, `SIGINT`, etc is sent to the whole process group / job, not just to the guilty process; in a pipeline like `foo | bar &`, both `foo` and `bar` will be stopped.

[1] actually, `echo` is a shell built-in, it does not run as a separate process.